# Two computers, one DD-WRT router, one PPTP VPN to connect to - possible?

Tags: windows-7, router, vpn

I have a broadband internet connection at home.  I connect a wireless router to it.  The router gives all my local machines addresses.
My company has a VPN server located far far away.  I can connect to it using the simple PPTP client built into windows 7.  It works great.

However, I cannot connect two different computers in my local network to that same VPN.  Whatever computer connects first gets the connection and none others can use it.
Example:  I connect to the VPN on my desktop.  I cannot then connect to it through my laptop.  And vice versa.

I believe this has been asked many times before, in many forms.  But I see no clear answer.  I believe this is possble, just cannot find how.  This has been bugging me for years!

Comment: Works now? Or still having problems?

Comment: Did not work, just lost the computer VPN, and so disabled the PPTP on the router.  I did not know what to put in for the MPPE, as the encryption is optional, and all examples show required, but no alternatives.  I can't have it down for long periods, so gave up for now.  At least this is a possible route, just no time to properly investigate it at this time.

Answer (score 2):

DD-WRT comes with built-in PPTP client. This [tutorial](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Static_PPTP_VPN_Client) should fix it for you.

1. Login to your router
2. ON the main page go to Services Tab -> Vpn.
3. There's a section PPTP Client (just under PPTP server).
4. Enable it to see more options
5. Fill everything in as per your needs

Comment: I have looked at that, and get stumped pretty quickly.  I've already installed DD-WRT, so that part is not helpful.  But then the section called "Configure your PPTP CLient" mentions Administration->Services->Enable PPTP Client, and I do not even see that.  can you tell me - what is this tutorial trying to accomplish? replace my OS VPN with a router VPN connection?

Comment: Login to your router. ON the main page go to Services Tab -> Vpn. There's a section PPTP Client (just under PPTP server). Enable it to see more options. That's what I can find on my own router with DD-WRT installed. The tutorial has EVERYTHING in the tutorial including installation of DD-WRT so you can skip some parts.

Comment: Ok, found the screen for the PPTP client on the page.  Tried to create an account to edit the wiki, but only login is allowed, not creating a new account (argh).  The instructions should say login to Administration, and go to Services tab, then VPN sub tab.

Comment: Tutorial may need updates to newest version but more or less it's quite accurate.

Comment: Ok, I'm there.  But I do not know what the "Remote Subnet" should be.  This is not somethig I enter when setting up the windows client.  I can tell you that internally all of the machines have ip of the form 172.22.1.x - is that helpful?

Comment: Yes & No. You need to enter subnet for the remote network. If the ip of the remote network is 172.22.1.X then subnet should be 255.255.255.0 most likely.

Comment: so the subnet is the same as the subnet mask?

Comment: Oh ok. I see now. Well try 172.22.1.0 and 255.255.255.0 as a subnet mask.

Comment: How can I know if the VPN is working?  Do I need to reboot the router, tweak values, then try to ping something in 172.22.1.x?

Comment: apply the settings, it should work couple of seconds later. You can do constant ping 172.22.1.some_ip_that_works from laptop or so. and wait for results.