# Connecting one PPTP router through another PPPoE router

Tags: networking, vpn, dd-wrt

First of all - I have to say that when it comes to networks , I am not a real expert - I have the basic knowledge of the decent programmer I am ..

I am trying to connect two routers , using one as normal WAN - internet connection  and another one as wireless VPN connection.

Router 1 :

```
Firmware: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (03/25/13) mega
Connection PPPoE
Username:password  [ OK ] 
Local IP 192.168.1.199
Subnet mask : 255.255.255.0
DHCP server : [ ON ] - starting from 192.168.1.7 max 7 
DNSMasq for DHCP  [ ON ]
DNSMasq for DNS  [ ON ]

IPSec Passthrough  [ ON ] 
PPTP Passthrough  [ ON ] 
L2TP Passthrough  [ ON ] 

Status : Working - Internet is ok ;

WAN IP 118.xx.xx.xxx.
```

Router 2

[ problem is here ]

```
Firmware: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (12/22/14) giga 
Connection PPTP
Username:password  [ OK - verified 10 times . account is solid ] 
Local IP 192.168.2.200
Subnet mask : 255.255.255.0
DHCP server : [ ON ] - starting from 192.168.2.100 max 50 
DNSMasq for DHCP  [ ON ]
DNSMasq for DNS  [ ON ]

IPSec Passthrough  [ ON ] 
PPTP Passthrough  [ ON ] 
L2TP Passthrough  [ ON ]
```

Basically the same , except for IP of course

Now, if I check the WAN status on Router 2 I see :

```
WAN IP: 192.168.1.12 

Connection Type  :PPTP  
Login Status : Disconnected  
Connection : Uptime Not available 
IP Address : 192.168.1.12 ( From router 1 DHCP ..)
Subnet Mask : 0.0.0.0   (  !!! WHY ??? )
Gateway : 192.184.36.56 (  GATEWAY SEEMS RESOLVED OK ? )
DNS 1: 200.120.XX.XX (  RECIEVED OK ? .. and out of msy network )
DNS 2 : 200.120.XX.X1 (  RECIEVED OK ? .. and out of msy network )
```

So my question is : what is going on here ?

1. why is my subnet mask 0.0.0.0
2. why I can not connect even if the Gateway and DNS seems out of my
   network .
3. The strangest point is - This settings has worked in the past ( a
   week ago ) but something was changed - not by me , by error or not ,
   and now I just can not connect the two. - So what am I missing ?

   BTW - I have saw a similar [question](https://superuser.com/questions/327488/two-computers-one-dd-wrt-router-one-pptp-vpn-to-connect-to-possible) , which I read and tried - but no help ..
   Any help would be greatly appreciated ...

**Edit I** ( after @qasdfdsaq comment)

I

I am trying to connect to a VPN service ,and My routers are connected as follow:
Router 1 - WAN ( internet ) port connected directly to Modem .
Router 2 - WAN ( internet ) port connected to Router 1 Lan port.

Here are the screenshots as requested ( did not attached before because did not wanted to overflow - sorry )

**Router 1 basic setup :**

[image: Router 1 basic setup]:

**Router 1 Security (VPN ) setup :**

[image: Router 1 Security]:

( Router 2 is exactly the same )

**Router 1 WAN Status screen :**

[image: Router 1 WAN Status screen]

**Router 2 basic setup :**

[image: Router 2 basic setup]

**Router 2 Wan Status Screen :**

[image: Router 2 Wan Status Screen]

I must add that the DNS on router 2 WAN status screen sometimes shows the IP of router 1 ( like above ) and sometimes the two DNS that are actuall listed on router 1..

I hope  that answers the doubts from comment .
Any help would be greatly appreciated .

Comment: 1. Because PPTP doesn't have subnet masks. That's what the PP in PPTP stands for. 2. What are you trying to connect to, and how are the routers connected to each other? 3. Are you sure your information is right? Why is router 2 handing out DHCP addresses in router 1's range? 4. Provide screenshots, not strange copy-pastes that aren't copy-pastes

Comment: @qasdfdsaq - Thanks for your comment . 1 - I did not know that . Thanks . 2 - See my edit I . 3 - Yes, My information, as limited as is , is correct for my understanding .4 - see edit . screenshots provided .